# How to retrieve records for last few hours in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

theyI had a asp.net (vb) web application to store work overtime (OT) records.

In SQL server, the OT table likes this, e.g.:

```
ot_key | From Time        | To Time          | total_min
12     | 2011-09-22 10:00 | 2011-09-22 13:00 | 180
13     | 2011-09-24 14:00 | 2011-09-24 15:00 | 60
14     | 2011-09-23 12:00 | 2011-09-23 14:30 | 150
15     | 2011-09-24 18:00 | 2011-09-24 19:30 | 90
```

As user will input previous date OT records, so the records in db will not be in sequence. the date of records#14 is before records#13.

if user want to know which OT records cover the last 2 hours, the system should retrieve record **#15** (90mins) & **#13** (30mins) because they covers the final 2 hours.

How to write the SQL statement to retrieve the records ? Thanks

Joe

Comment: Your data looks strange : the ToTime for #13 is one day before the FromTime. Please check.

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Just select the records with total_min lower than two hours ?

Comment: Following the TDD mantra, a simple `SELECT * FROM OTTable WHERE total_min <= 120`.

Comment: hi, louis, for your question "#13 is one day before the FromTime", it is because user will input previous date OT records, so the records will not be in sequence.

Comment: Sorry for confusing all of you. I had revised my question, hope it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, all you need to do is this (but its weird the way you phrased your question, so I'm not sure this what you are looking for.

```
 select * from OT where total_min <=
 [number of hours expressed in minutes]
```

Comment: This just gets the entries where the time difference is less than 2 hours, not what have been posted the past 2 hours.

Comment: @Nicolai, true but OP wants record 15 & 13 returned. Record 13 ends at 15:00 hours, record 15 at 19:30. This can never be returned for *the past two hours*. The requirements given by OP are wrong or at least incomplete.

Comment: Sorry for confusing all of you. I had revised my question, hope it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE OT (
    [ot_key] INT,
    [From Time] DATETIME,
    [To Time] DATETIME,
    [total_min] INT
)

INSERT  OT
VALUES  (12,'2011-09-22 10:00', '2011-09-22 13:00', 180),
        (13, '2011-09-24 14:00', '2011-09-24 15:00', 60),
        (14, '2011-09-23 12:00', '2011-09-23 14:30', 150),
        (15, '2011-09-24 18:00', '2011-09-24 19:30', 90)
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @CoverTime INT = 120

;WITH cteOTRN AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [To Time] DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], *
    FROM OT
)
, cteOTRT AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cteOTRN ot
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  SUM([total_min]) AS [RunningTotal]
        FROM cteOTRN
        WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] <= ot.[ROW_NUMBER]
    ) rt
)
SELECT *, [total_min] AS [CoverTime]
FROM cteOTRT ot
WHERE [RunningTotal] <= @CoverTime
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 *, [RunningTotal] - @CoverTime
FROM cteOTRT ot
WHERE NOT ([RunningTotal] <= @CoverTime)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cteOTRT ot
    WHERE [RunningTotal] = @CoverTime
)
ORDER BY [To Time] DESC
```

See also [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
select * from OT where datediff(hour,ToTime,getdate()) < 2
```

which will give you the posts where the difference between currenttime and totime is less than 2 hours.

Comment: this may well be wat OP *intended* but it will not return records 13 & 15.

Comment: Sorry for confusing all of you. I had revised my question, hope it will be better.